# Melhora de performance de código simples em C

Tags: c, desempenho

eu tive uma prova em que a questão era :

Cosiderando que os períodos da história são quatro:

(1) período anterior a 4000 aC;

(2) de 3999 aC até 476 dC;

(3) de 477 dC até 1789 dC; e

(4) após 1790 dC.

Observar que aC corresponde a antes de Cristo, e dC corresponde a depois de Cristo, e o marco de nascimento de Cristo é o ano 0 (zero).

Escrever função que tem como parâmetros de entrada, o ano e referência quanto à era cristã, e retornar o número correspondente ao respectivo período da história: 1,2, 3 ou 4. Em seguida, ler 3 pares de ano e referência à era cristã e identificar a mais recente (maior).
o formato de saida é :
3 pares de ano e referência à era cristã, cada uma em linha distinta.

eu fiz o codigo na prova e depois submeti para um site onde avaliava o tempo de execução, e outros alunos fizeram o mesmo.  Meu codigo feito em C não foi o mais rapido, outros fizeram em C e tiveram um tempo de execução melhor, por isso eu gostaria de saber como melhorar o tempo de execução desse codigo, onde eu estou errando, se há alguma redundância, para poder fazer códigos melhores, o código é o seguinte:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

char buffer1[8],buffer2[8],buffer3[8],buffer[8];

int Ano,i,space,Anos[3],cont=0;

char letra,letras[4];

char st_int[5];

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
gets(buffer1);
gets(buffer2);          //RECEBE OS DADOS
gets(buffer3);
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 //------------------------------------------------------------------------   
inicio:
if(cont==0)strcpy(buffer,buffer1);
else if(cont==1)strcpy(buffer,buffer2);
else strcpy(buffer,buffer3);
for(i=0;i<8;i++){
space=buffer[i];                            //TRATA OS DADOS DA ENTRADA
if(space == 32){
    letra=buffer[i+1];
    st_int[i]='\0'; Ano=atoi(st_int);//printf("Ano=!%d!\n",Ano);
    break;
    }
st_int[i]=buffer[i];
}

if(cont<=2){
    letras[cont]=letra; Anos[cont]=Ano;
cont++;
if(cont<=2)goto inicio;
}
letras[cont]='\0';
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
for(i=0;i<=2;i++){
    //printf("entrou\n");
    if(letras[i] == 'a'){
        if(Anos[i]>4000){
            Anos[i]=1;continue;
            }                     //VERIFICA EM QUAL ERA OS ANOS SE ENCAIXAM
        if(Anos[i]<=3999){
            Anos[i]=2;continue;            
        }
    }
    if(letras[i]=='d'){
        if((Anos[i]>=0) && (Anos[i]<=476)){
            Anos[i]=2;continue;
        }
        if((Anos[i]>=477) && (Anos[i]<=1789)){
            Anos[i]=3;continue;
        }
        if(Anos[i]>=1790){
            Anos[i]=4;continue;
        }
    }
    }
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
if(Anos[0]>Anos[1])
    cont=Anos[0];                     //VERIFICA QUAL O MAIOR VALOR DA ERA
else
    cont=Anos[1];
if(Anos[1]>Anos[2])
    cont=Anos[1];
else
    cont=Anos[2];
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
printf("\n%d",cont);  //MOSTRA O RESULTADO FINAL

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
    }
```

Agradeço qualquer dica/crítica/conselho para melhorar a performance desse codigo e dos próximos que farei.

Comment: Bom, pra começar, todas as chamadas de `strcpy` gastam tempo precioso de forma desnecessária. Tente declarar `buffer` como `char *buffer` e fazer `buffer = buffer3` (por exemplo) no lugar de fazer a cópia. Já verá alguma melhora. Outra coisa: a linha com `letra=buffer[i+1];` tem uma potencial invasão de memória, quando o `i` for igual a 7 (isto é, se por algum acaso tiver um espaço na última posição).

Comment: Quando você diz que o desempenho foi pior, de quantos porcento estamos falando? Eu não vi nada gritantemente ineficiente no seu código, no máximo acho que você poderia evitar os 3 `strcpy` usando referências/ponteiros em vez disso (você já estudou ponteiros?). O resto é micro-otimização, não sei se vale a pena esquentar com isso. A propósito, esse `system("PAUSE")` no final não interfere com a análise de tempo de execução, certo?

Comment: Não tinha pensado sobre esse modo de usar ponteiros para substituir strcpy que vocês falaram, apesar de ja saber ponteiros e ter usado isso em alguns casos sem nem perceber que podia fazer isso. Realmente foi de grande ajuda, obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Segue uma solução bem eficiente para o problema:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int parse_data( const char * str )
{
    int ano;

    ano = atoi(str);

    if( ano == 0 )
        return 2;

    if( strchr( str, 'a' ) )
    {
        if( ano > 4000 )
            return 1;
        else    
            return 2;
    }

    if( strchr( str, 'b' ) )
    {
        if( ano <= 476 )
            return 2;

        if( (ano >= 477) && (ano <= 1789) )
            return 3;

        if( ano > 1789 )
            return 4;
    }

    return -1;
}


int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    int ret;
    char data[ 16 ];

    printf("Data: ");
    fgets( data, sizeof(data), stdin );

    ret = parse_data( data );

    printf("\nCodigo: %d\n", ret );

    return 0;
}

/* fim-de-arquivo */
```

Espero que ajude!

Comment: achei bom como tu fizeste de uma forma tão sucinta, mas quanto a função strchr() não diminui a performance ja que está se fazendo mais uma chamada de função?